# How to change Constraint Layout's child view's Constraints programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the constraints of the togglebutton programmatically, but I am already set constraints to the togglebutton in xml file .What I need is when I click a togglebutton i want to override the constraints of the togglebutton i.e., when i click on togglebutton1 then add constraints from left side of togglebutton2 with the left side of togglebutton3 with marging 0.

```
private ToggleButton toggleButton1;
private ToggleButton toggleButton2;
private ToggleButton toggleButton3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    toggleButton3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener compoundButton = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout); 
                ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                set.clone(constraintLayout);
                set.connect(toggleButton3.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,toggleButton2.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
                set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
            } else
               // somecode
        }
    };
    toggleButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(compoundButton);
}
```

hope someone help me

Comment: After removing the setContentView second time also it's not working.

Comment: Are you trying to redraw the layout?

Comment: I am trying to override the constraints of togglebutton in the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution for you, but I can show you something that convinces me that connect is not working right/left as it does top/bottom. Change your `OnCheckedChangeListener` code to the following and run it.

```
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener compoundButton = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            set.clone(constraintLayout);
            if (isChecked) {
                set.connect(toggleButton3.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, toggleButton2.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
            } else {
                set.connect(toggleButton3.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, toggleButton2.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
            }
            set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        }
    };
```

When you first click the toggleButton1, you will not see a change. When you click it a second time, you should see toggleButton3 jump so its bottom aligns with the bottom of toggleButton2. (Make sure it doesn't line up to begin with.)

Your issue may be related to [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545).

If you do find a solution, it would be great for you to post it as an answer here since I have run across this issue a number of times.

I hope that helps.

---

**EDIT**
Here is what you can do to fix this. Use `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` instead of `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT`. I just tried it and it works OK. I can't say why left and right don't work.